# Cocos2d particle system dont follow moving and rotating camera

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to create a fire particle system on a sprite when its hit by another sprite:

```
void MySprite::hit()
{
    auto ps = cocos2d::ParticleFire::create();
    ps->setPositionType(cocos2d::ParticleSystem::PositionType::RELATIVE);
    this->addChild(ps);
}
```

I use 'setPosition3D' and 'lookAt' methods for moveing camera in the scene.
when i move camera, the particle system stuck in the screen (and always has a fixed position in the window) and dont follow the parent sprite!

I try different position type, Follow action, setSourcePosition method, but the problem not solved.

I use cocos2d-x v3.3 and C++ in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I used two camera, one for HUD (CameraFlag::DEFAULT) and another for the scene (CameraFlag::USER1). i forgot to set camera flag for particle system:

```
ps->setCameraMask(cocos2d::CameraFlag::USER1);
```

and particle system shown by default camera.